# What is the passive voice of this sentence?

Tags: grammar

I want to know the passive voice of this sentence "     ".

Comment: Sounds terrible, but totally passive: _He should be told by you that the room must be left by him._

Comment: There's no passive equivalent of your example. The closest would be "He should be told to leave the room", but it's not an exact passive equivalent of your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence actually contains **two** imperatives:

- Tell him
- Leave the room

The passive voice of these two commands *in isolation* would be:

- Let him be told
- Let the room be left

However, your original sentence is an active command to deliver a message to somebody else in the active voice. To change *this* sentence to passive voice, you need only to change the imperative that is directed at the hearer, so the answer to your question would be:

> Let him be told to leave the room.

However, you *could* also passively request someone deliver a message in the passive voice. If you wanted to change *both* to passive, then it would be:

> Let him be told that the room must be left.

Comment: Actually, the only imperative is the matrix "Tell him ....", where the _understood_ subject of "tell"  is "you". The subject of the infinitival clause "to leave the room" is not understood as "you", but as "him".

Comment: @BillJ Agreed, that's why I said that it contained two "in isolation". I've made some minor edits to try and make that clearer. I suspect that this question has been posed to the OP, and has been designed to highlight this issue.